# CollectionView choppy scrolling

Tags: asynchronous, uicollectionview

Researched here and there but probably missing something.
Using SDWeb for caching.

My aim is to preload 20 cells once I reach the 10th :

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell,
                          forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.item == (loadingPostCount - 10) {loadFeed()}
}
```

My loadFeed() that calls other methods to do the dirty work:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async  {
    self.loadingPostCount = self.posts.count + 20
    query?.queryLimited(toLast: 21).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        if let reversed = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot], !reversed.isEmpty {
            self.nextEntry = reversed[0].key
            self.collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({
                for index in stride(from: reversed.count - 1, through: 1, by: -1) {
                    self.loadItem(reversed[index])
                }
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    })        
}
```

What happens is that once I reach the 10th cell the scrolling is blocked so I supposed I am doing something wrong on the async thread. Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: The line

    `if indexPath.item == (loadingPostCount - 10) {loadFeed()}`

looks suspicious to me.  I suspect you are repeatedly calling `loadFeed()` each time your `collectionView( willDisplay...` method is called whenever indexPath.item hits that magic row number.  If you set an Xcode breakpoint in `loadFeed()`, do you see it hitting multiple times, or at all?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, it is called 4 times just before starting the scrolling. So how I can call loadFeed() just when user reaches the 10xn cell?

Comment: Went a bit further on this. Changed forItemAt to be if indexPath.item == 10 {loadFeed()}. Now the first 20 cells are loaded in didLoad. Once I hit the 10th all is blocked because loadFeed is working. This sounds to me like I am not using asynctask at all. So how can I use async task properly in this case so I can have a buttery scroll?